# How to set cookie in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5.4

I have this function in laravel 5.4 but I cant get anything from cookie.

```
Cookie::queue('currentLang', 'heb', 999999999);

echo  $request->cookie('currentLang');
```

But I am getting some long string and not what I set.

Comment: What are the long strings? Are they `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis`?

Comment: Were you putting this in the constructor of a controller? Cookies only get decrypted afterwards, so you have to decrypt them yourself https://laravel.io/forum/09-07-2015-cookies-encrypted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel has a cookie helper!

```
/**
 * Create a new cookie instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  int     $minutes
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  string  $domain
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @param  bool    $httpOnly
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie
 */
function cookie($name = null, $value = null, $minutes = 0, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = true)
{
    $cookie = app(CookieFactory::class);

    if (is_null($name)) {
        return $cookie;
    }

    return $cookie->make($name, $value, $minutes, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
}
```

then use:

```
Cookie::get('$name')
```

Comment: Where I can put this function?

Comment: just replace your Cookie::queue with cookie('name', 'value', 99999);

the function itself exists in the helpers.php of laravel - so you can use it everywhere

Comment: I am still getting some hash long line

Answer (score 4):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

Cookie::queue('currentLang', 'heb', 999999999);

echo Cookie::get('currentLang');
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face to the same issue. it returns null so I have done it using Javascript and PHP like

Setting value in cookie using Javascript

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        var expires;
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else {
            expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }
```

Retriving cookie using PHP

```
$_COOKIE["popupId"]
```